# How to manage user's timezone in Rails right?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I know that there's quite a lot of gems that do the job, but I think it's quite excessive to use a whole gem for such an easy task.

I found that js does it pretty easy:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

The answer is a string like `"Europe/Moscow"`.

We can easily save it to db

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :time_zone, default: "UTC"
  ...
end
```

and set user's time zone like:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
around_action :set_time_zone, if: :current_user

private

def set_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
end
```

So my ***question*** is: Am I missing something important (why these gems are being used) or I can do it like I wrote above (without any gems)?

*Inspired by the [ThoughtBot's article](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-offset-in-javascript)*

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO ;) If you mean displaying the locale date *on the front-end* you could use Javascript's `toLocaleDateString` and `toLocaleTimeString` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything important. Every language has different kinds and numbers of bells and whistles adorning its basic parts. The specification for "[ECMAScript Internationalization API](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/)" (what gives you the power to write `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`) wasn't introduced until 2012, some years after JavaScript was first conceived.

Somewhat similarly on the back end, the Rails framework provides its own API baked in, allowing you to create `Time` instances with the added accuracy and functionality of the `TZInfo` gem thanks to Rails' `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` wrapper. You don't even have too stray to far from what you might be used to in Ruby, intuitively calling both `Time` and `TZInfo` methods on `Time` in Rails.

The code you wrote above technically relies on a gem. Rails is a gem! Maybe the delineation you're going for is whether we should use libraries that come *with* our languages and frameworks or reach *out* for new ones. That difference is not as important as how dependable the libraries are in the first place. So you aren't missing anything! It's just a jungle out there :)